# Magento 2 : get custom attribute options from custom eav entity type

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes

In **magento 2.3.1**, I created custom `eav_entity_type` and attribute also assign under that custom `eav_entity_type`.

Now, I added attribute options programmatically in that attribute and that record I saved in `eav_attribute_options` and `eav_attribute_options_value` tables.

Now, I used this below code for get that all options. But, I return blank array.

```
 /*Get attribute details*/
    $attributeDetails = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute("custom_eav_entity_type", 'custom_eav_attr');
    print_r($attributeDetails->getData()); //return blanks
```

How do I get that all options?

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to get attribute type where it is Select, text etc...?

Comment: No. I added attribute in custom eav_entity_type and my custom attribute save under custom eav_entity_type. For ex: color attribute save under catalog_product eav_entity_type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('eav_entity_type_code', 'attributecode');
$attributeoptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: That's working. But, I want from custom eav_entity_type.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. In that case, replace `catalog_product` with your custom `eav_entity_type_code`. If it's still not work, so check this tutorial http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-creating-new-eav-entity-and-model may be you miss some thing during creation of custom eav_entity_type